# How to insert Bulk data into Neo4j using Python

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I want to insert some data into `Neo4j` using `py2neo` . [Link](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Facebook.html) to data file.
I am new to `Neo4j`. Can someone tell me how to insert bulk data into `Neo4j`.Actually i want to do performance testing of `Neo4j`.....

I have tried this but this is just for small data set ...

```
from pprint import pprint
from py2neo import neo4j,node, rel
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()

def insert_data():
    die_hard = graph_db.create(
        node(name="Bruce Willis"),
        node(name="John McClane"),
        node(name="Alan Rickman"),
        node(name="Hans Gruber"),
        node(name="Nakatomi Plaza"),
        rel(0, "PLAYS", 1),
        rel(2, "PLAYS", 3),
        rel(1, "VISITS", 4),
        rel(3, "STEALS_FROM", 4),
        rel(1, "KILLS", 3),)
    pprint(die_hard)

insert_data()
```

error :

```
src/test/java/org/neo4j/batchimport/TestDataGenerator.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Ignore;
                ^
src/test/java/org/neo4j/batchimport/TestDataGenerator.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
@Ignore
 ^
  symbol: class Ignore
2 errors
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to perform bulk add/insert in Neo4j with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643662/fastest-way-to-perform-bulk-add-insert-in-neo4j-with-python)

Comment: I have tried [batch-import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) but it is not working ...can anyone help me

Comment: Is there any standard benchmark for `Neo4j`

Comment: I have found this [link](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-1/) ....But it is giving error

Comment: Do you have that code somewhere? I don't see you referencing the batchinserter classes anywhere here, seems like a setup problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the issue you're having, but when I tried your sample, I got errors on the [name=] syntax.  What's being passed to the node() constructor is a dictionary.  There are multiple syntax for the node() constructor, and I didn't see a syntax that matches the one your using.  So, try using dictionary syntax like this:

```
node({"name": "Bruce Willis"})
```

Also, I'm not sure if you've configured a default neo4j url, but I had to specify a connection point url in my new4j.GraphDatabaseService() call.

So, your code would look like:

```
from pprint import pprint
from py2neo import neo4j, node, rel
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService('http://localhost:7474/db/data')

def insert_data():
    die_hard = graph_db.create(
        node({"name": "Bruce Willis"}),
        node({"name": "John McClane"}),
        node({"name": "Alan Rickman"}),
        node({"name": "Hans Gruber"}),
        node({"name": "Nakatomi Plaza"}),
        rel(0, "PLAYS", 1),
        rel(2, "PLAYS", 3),
        rel(1, "VISITS", 4),
        rel(3, "STEALS_FROM", 4),
        rel(1, "KILLS", 3),)
    pprint(die_hard)

insert_data()
```

Comment: I tried this but I get this error:      >>> from py2neo import neo4j, node, rel
>>> g = neo4j.Graph()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py", line 526, in __new__
    uri = ServiceRoot().graph.uri.string
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py", line 452, in graph
    self.__graph = Graph(self.resource.metadata["data"])
KeyError: u'data'

Answer (score 4):

I'd highly recommend you use the '[Geoff](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff)' format which stands for 'Graph Export Object File Format'.

In this method you basically generate a text file containing nodes and relationship information which is then used to populate the database in a batch insert.

The '[Load2Neo](http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo)' module is used to batch insert the information.

Having used it, I can say it is extremely fast. Make sure you check out the simple documentation [here](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff). As long as you follow the syntax rules, you'll have a smooth experience with Geoff!

Geoff has been developed by Nigel Small, who also is the author of Py2Neo (the python driver for Neo4j). It you run into issues and want quick help, make sure you fire Nigel a [tweet](http://twitter.com/technige). He helps out!

Comment: I've parsed my data in the geoff format, but when I try to run the Bulk Load command line: `http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo` nothing happens.

I run it at the same directory where my geoff file is (which is not the same directory as the server, is that a problem?) and while my server is on at `http://localhost:7474/` but nothing happens.

Can someone point out what am I missing here? Thanks!