# How do I import Python node dicts into neo4j?

Tags: python, json, neo4j, py2neo

I produce the following node and relationship data in a for loop about 1 million times. The idea is that `investor` nodes connect to `company` nodes by `relationship` edges:

```
investor = {'name': owner['name'],
            'CIK': owner['CIK']}

relationship = {'isDirector': owner['isDirector'],
                'isOfficer': owner['isOfficer'],
                'isOther': owner['isOther'],
                'isTenPercentOwner': owner['isTenPercentOwner'],
                'title': owner['title']}

company = {'Name': json['issuerName'],
           'SIC': json['issuerSIC'],
           'Ticker Symbol': json['issuerTradingSymbol'],
           'CIK': json['issuerCIK'],
           'EIN': json['issuerEIN']}
```

How do I complete the following code to get the dicts above into neo4j community edition?

```
from py2neo import Graph, authenticate 

authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "neo")
graph = Graph()

for json in long_list_of_dicts:
    investor = {...}
    company = {...}
    relationship  = {...}

    # Code to import investor, company, relationship data into neo4j
```

Answer (score 0):

In py2neo a **Node** is defined in following manner:

`class Node(*labels, **properties)`

Each `node` has a `label` and can have many `properties`. In this case, Investor node can de defined by setting the label *investor* and properties of the node to be *name* and *CIK*.

```
investor_node = Node('investor', name = owner['name'], CIK = owner['CIK'])
```

Similarly, company node would look like:

```
company_node = Node('company', name = json['issuerName'], SIC = json['issuerSIC'])
```

Relationship are defined in following manner :

`class Relationship(start_node, type, end_node, **properties)`

In this case **Relationship** can be defined using:

```
investor_company_relationship = Relationship(investor_node, "is_director", company_node)
```

You can find one sample implementation of neo4j graph [here](https://github.com/shubham2892/snap-facebook-neo4j/blob/master/snap_facebook.py).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNWIND` clause. Something like

```
WITH {json} AS document
UNWIND document AS company
MERGE (c:company {c_id:company.id})
 SET c.sic=company.issuerSIC
```

If some of your json items is list again, you can use UNWIND as much as you like: `UNWIND document.list_of_some_property`